# Celebrate title after red card

Tags: football

If a player receives a red card during the final of a football tournament and leaves the pitch, can he goes back and celebrate the title, if his team wins? Do you remember such a case?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes; the French player Marcel Desailly got sent off during the [1998 World Cup final against Brasil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1998_FIFA_World_Cup_Final#Details) but there are many pictures of him celebrating, like the one below (he's the one in the blue shirt with number 8):

[image]

([source](http://www.abc.net.au/news/2014-05-13/desailly-laps-it-up-after-france-beat-brazil-in-1998-world-cup-/5449408): ABC News, Getty Images, Lutz Bongarts)

Comment: Nice answer, congrats for your 1k :)

Comment: Thank you, I promise to put my edit privileges to good use here.

Answer (score 6):

Schalke 04 vs Bayer Leverkusen [[2001-02 DFB Pokal final (4-2)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2002_DFB-Pokal_Final)]

Victor Agali got sent off and went back on the pitch to celebrate.

[image]

Image source: [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l-fN-Ipnvus)